# Can't connect to Bluetooth speakers

Tags: release-hera, bluetooth

So I'm running an Asus X5501CA on eOS 5.1 Hera (Built on Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS | Linux 5.3.0-26-generic | Linux 5.3.0-26-generic).

Have Qualcomm bluetooth hardware card. So anyway up until a few days ago my laptop was connecting just fine with my SONY SRS XB10. But as of yesterday, I can't connect to my bluetooth speaker. I tried using blueman bluetooth manager, nothing.

Don't know what the issue is. The speaker connects well with Windows 10 (same laptop), and my Android phone.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Just a question ... did you check settings / sound / output for where the sound is being directed to ???

Comment: I think I have the same problem - few weeks ago it started to fail connecting to my Jbuds earpods. They connect fine to my android phone and tablet. I have another laptop with eOS that I forgot to test, so I will do today and see if it's HW or SW fault.